# Unhandled exception at 0x0119D329 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 preview.
In a current project I'm working on, I've got a pointer that points to an array of pointers.
for example,

at the beginning of my class

```
string ** pointer;
```

then in my constructor, I have:

```
int size = 10;
pointer = new node * [size];
```

when I try to run my code, though, it compiles but when running I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0119D329 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

when I tell it to break, the error seems to be at:

```
pointer = new node * [size];
```

Does anyone have any information on what this error would be referring to and how I can fix it?

Comment: I see no clear connection between the type `string` and the type `node`.  You seem to declare `pointer` to indirectly reference strings, but allocate space for `nodes`.  ***show more code***

Comment: What sort of type is `node`? You're using `new`, so it looks like a class, but it's lowercase. Also, as @abelenky mentioned, you're assigning it to what looks like an unrelated type.